# Delphi 7 get folder name from path

Tags: delphi, string

I have a path say C:\Program Files\Borland
what would bet the easiest way to parse that string and just return Borland?
thanks

Answer (score 31):

try using the [ExtractFileName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.ExtractFileName) function, this function only works (for your example) if your path not finalize with an backslash, so you can use the [ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter) function to remove the final backslash.

see this sample

```
program ProjectExtractPathDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
    Path : string ;
begin
  Path:='C:\Program Files\Borland';
  Writeln(ExtractFileName(Path));//return Borland

  Path:='C:\Program Files\Borland\';
  Writeln(ExtractFileName(Path));//return ''

  Path:='C:\Program Files\Borland\';
  Writeln(ExtractFileName(ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Path)));//return Borland


  Readln;
end.
```

check this link for more info

[Path Manipulation Routines](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Path_Manipulation_Routines)

Comment: I never know ExtractFileName would work on a directory.
Perfect.
Thanks.

Comment: +1 I would have tried to use ExtractFilePath for folders and ExtractFileName for files.

Answer (score 8):

You can get whatever comes after the last backslash with `ExtractFileName`, which is found in the SysUtils unit.

Answer (score 2):

This will work on all folders whether it has a trailing back slash or not:

```
ExtractFileName(ExcludeTrailingBackslash(Path))
```

Answer (score 1):

To directly parse that string and just return "Borland", you can do this:

```
uses SysUtils;

Delete(Path, 1, LastDelimiter('\', Path));
```